# How to extract variable part from URL and how to know if URL variable is appended by digits?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this:

```
www.example.com/education/edu.php?Main=Colleges&Category=Engineering-colleges
```

I Rewrite this URL using `.htaccess`

```
www.example.com/education/Colleges/Engineering-colleges
```

Also I have another URL in this same `education` directory like:

```
www.example.com/education/eduS.php?Main=Colleges&CollegeId=$Id&CollegeName=$Name
```

I want to rewrite this URL like this:

```
www.example.com/education/Colleges/$Name-sqr$Id
```

How can this be accomplished? I can't think of a way to do this because above two rewrite URLs have the same number of parameters. So I can't redirect them to the correct page.

These are my questions:

- Is there any way using `.htaccess` for validating URL variable with `sqr$Id` and redirecting to `eduS.php` page.
- How to extract the `Id` from that URL and make for that variable for operation in that page.

Comment: Can you post your existing .htaccess code?

Comment: @anubhava  <br/>RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]  <br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  <br/>
RewriteRule .+ - [L]  <br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ eduS.php?Main=$1&String=$2 [L,NC,QSA]  <br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ edu.php?Main=$1&Category=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your `/education/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /education/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^-]+)-sqr([0-9]+)/?$ eduS.php?Main=$1&CollegeId=$3&CollegeName=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ eduS.php?Main=$1&Category=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: ^([^/]+)/([^-]+)-sqr([0-9]+)/?$ why '/?' (at the end) in this rule.. Is it necessary?

Comment: That is for precisely matching `/Colleges/$Name-sqr$Id` part. Is there any problem with that regex?

Comment: Oh not a problem, you can ask/clarify any number of questions. I was just checking if answer is working for you, glad to know it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using different regular expressions. I suppose you are already doing that, so you could only apply a rule something like that:

```
(\w+)\-sqr(\d+)
```

By the way, wouldn't it look better to use id-name?

```
(\d+)\-(\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)-sqr([0-9]+)$ eduS.php?Main=$1&CollegeId=$3&CollegeName=$2 [L]
```

in your "education" folder. It should go *before* the other rule that you have that rewrites to `edu.php`. If your rule is in the document root, then it needs to look like:

```
RewriteRule ^education/([^/]+)/([^/]+)-sqr([0-9]+)$ /education/eduS.php?Main=$1&CollegeId=$3&CollegeName=$2 [L]
```